# SQL Update First record of Duplicate row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am looking to update the first record when a duplicate is found in a table.

```
CREATE TABLE tblauthor 
    (
     Col1 varchar(20), 
     Col2 varchar(30)   
    );

CREATE TABLE tblbook 
    (
     Col1 varchar(20), 
     Col2 varchar(30),
     Col3 varchar(30)     
    );

INSERT INTO tblAuthor
(Col1,Col2)
VALUES
('1', 'John'),
('2', 'Jane'),
('3', 'Jack'),
('4', 'Joe');

INSERT INTO tblbook
(Col1,Col2,Col3)
VALUES
('1', 'John','Book 1'),
('2', 'John','Book 2'),
('3', 'Jack','Book 1'),
('4', 'Joe','Book 1'),
('5', 'Joe','Book 2'),
('6', 'Jane','Book 1'),
('7', 'Jane','Book 2');
```

The update result I want to accomplish should update the records as follows. I would like tblbook.col3 = 1st.

```
select * from tblbook

('1', 'John','1st'),
('3', 'Jack','1st'),
('4', 'Joe','1st'),
('6', 'Jane','1st');
```

Can't seem to even get this done with distinct.

Comment: sql fiddle [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b6c8/1

Comment: What means you want to update, why does your desired result only contain unique records? Do you instead want to delete the others? I would also change your sample data above like you did in sql-fiddle since that does currently not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to assign a number to each row grouped by the Author's name (`col2`) and then update the ones that have a number of `1`

```
update tblbook set col3 = '1st'
where col1 in(
    select
        col1
    from (
        select 
            tblbook.col1,
            tblbook.col2,
            tblbook.col3,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tblbook.Col2 order by tblbook.col1) as rownum
        from tblbook 
            left outer join tblauthor on tblbook.col2 = tblauthor.col2
    ) [t1]
    where [t1].rownum = 1
)
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b6c8/20/0

Comment: Worked to perfection.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `tblbook` so the third column is `'1st'` on duplicates, then you can easily do so with an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select tbl2.*, row_number() over (partition by col2 order by col1) as seqnum
      from tbl2
     )
update toupdate
    set col3 = '1st'
    where seqnum = 1;
```

This is the closest that I can come to understanding what you really want.

Comment: I haven't tried yours yet, but I will give a try on sqlfiddle.  Thanks.